# How to Segue from a table filled with results from search controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchcontroller

The old UISearchDisplayController class is now deprecated and instead we have to use the new UISearchController. There used to be a property in the old class called "SearchResultsTableView" but it's gone from the new class.

I populate a table with data and all works as intended - including segueing each row's details to another scene. I throw a search bar in there (programmatically - using the new searchController) and it successfully reloads the original table with any found results.
HOWEVER, when touching a selected row after a search, the segue passed along is that of the original table row that happens to be in the same position of the one touched now! (i.e. if I choose the current second row of a search, the next scene will segue the details of the second row of the original table!) That's because despite the data in the rows are being successfuly repopulated with the search data, the index numbers are still those of the old data.

It used to be with the old type that we would check this as such:

```
if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
let indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
} else {
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
```

So I think that with the old UISearchDisplayController class you actually got a new table, whereas with the new SearchController Class you only get new rows inside the old table? This totaly doesn't make sense !

Here is my full code per request:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class secondTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()




//these 2 are standard for the title and subtitle
var TableTitle:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var TableSub:Array< String > = Array < String >()

//the following are for my seque to next scene
var the_fname:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var the_basics:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var the_p_method:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var the_seats:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var the_notes:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var the_tableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()





override func viewDidLoad() {


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    self.title = currentBus


    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)



        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()




    var url = "http://the_path_to_my_json_file"

    get_data_from_url(url)

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // 2
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return TableTitle.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondtableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
//cell.detailTextLabel?.text = TableSub[indexPath.row]
}else{
cell.textLabel?.text = TableTitle[indexPath.row]
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = TableSub[indexPath.row]



    }
    return cell



}


func get_data_from_url(url:String)
{
    let httpMethod = "GET"
    let timeout = 15
    let url = NSURL(string: url)

    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!,
        cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 15.0)
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
        urlRequest,
        queue: queue,
        completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,
            data: NSData!,
            error: NSError!) in
            if data.length > 0 && error == nil{
                let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                self.extract_json(json!)
            }else if data.length == 0 && error == nil{
                println("Nothing was downloaded")
            } else if error != nil{
                println("Error happened = \(error)")
            }
        }
    )
}






func extract_json(data:NSString)
{
    var parseError: NSError?
    let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &parseError)
    if (parseError == nil)
    {
        if let my_pass_list = json as? NSArray
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < my_pass_list.count ; i++ )
            {
                if let each_pass = my_pass_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let fname = each_pass["fname"] as? String
                    {
                        if let lname = each_pass["lname"] as? String
                        {
                            if let numofseats = each_pass["numofseats"] as? String
                            {
                                if let showed_up = each_pass["showed_up"] as? String
                                {
                                    if let res_id = each_pass["resnum"] as? String
                                    {
                                        if let res_notes = each_pass["res_notes"] as? String
                                        {
                                            if let payment_description = each_pass["payment_description"] as? String
                                            {




                                                // the_tableData.append(fname)
                                                the_fname.append(fname)
                                                the_basics.append(fname + " " + lname)
                                                the_p_method.append(payment_description)
                                                the_seats.append(numofseats)
                                                the_notes.append(res_notes)

                                                TableTitle.append(fname + " " + lname)
                                                TableSub.append("Seats Reserved: " + numofseats + ". Showed Up: " + showed_up + ". Notes:" + res_notes)

                                                the_tableData = TableTitle
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    do_table_refresh();
}


func do_table_refresh()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}






// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].

    var thirdScene = segue.destinationViewController as! customer_details_View_Controller

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

            /*
so what I'm missing is to be able to check
if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
and if yes have indexPath be the self.resultSearchController.resultSearchTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
or something of that nature
*/

            thirdScene.dotrav = todayString
            thirdScene.from = currentBus
            thirdScene.basics = the_basics[indexPath.row]
            thirdScene.p_method = the_basics[indexPath.row]
            thirdScene.seats = the_tableData[indexPath.row]
            thirdScene.notes = the_notes[indexPath.row]



        }
          // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (the_tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the fact that you are going to have different data in your tableView depending on the search result. You can still use `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.

What I do, is keep a reference to my base data, and then keep a reference to my filtered data, and display my filtered data in the `tableView` at all times. If my searchBar has no text, then my filtered data is equal to my base data.

Example:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var data: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

    var filteredData: [String]!

    var searchController: UISearchController!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpSearchController()
        setFilteredDataForCurrentSearch()
    }

    private func setUpSearchController() {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }


    private func setFilteredDataForCurrentSearch() {
        if let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text where !searchString.isEmpty {
            filteredData = data.filter({ (string: String) -> Bool in

                return searchString.rangeOfString(string, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil

            })
        } else {
            filteredData = data
        }
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        setFilteredDataForCurrentSearch()
    }

}
```

Now, you can implement all of your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods using the `filteredData`.

In `prepareForSegue`, you retrieve the correct selected object like:

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
let selectedObject = filteredData[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks. That would work fine if I had the data ready way up on top as in your example. However, the data is being fetched from an online page in JSON format and built inside the table asynchronously using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ` row by row.

Comment: In that case, you are going to need to find some way to keep track of the current data that is loaded as data enters and leaves memory so that you have a way of tracking what is displayed at each index path. I'd be happy to try and give you a better suggestion if I had a more specific example of your problem. Can you post some more sample code?

Comment: Well thanks much for your continued help. I've been struggling with this for more than a week. I originally posted my question last week, and then revised it for today's post as I thought I wasn't clear enough. That original post is: [here]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739258/accessing-index-path-row-after-search
At that post you will see how I do the cell creation, the search function and the segue. I'll post the code you're asked for in a separate comment due to the character constraints here in commenting

Comment: ..here goes:
`func extract_json(data:NSString)`

...and then I have typical JSON retrieval stuff:

 `if let my_pass_list = json as? NSArray{
for (var i = 0; i < my_pass_list.count ; i++ )
if let each_pass = my_pass_list[i] as? NSDictionary
 {
if let fname = each_pass["fname"] as? String
 {
 if let lname = each_pass["lname"] as? String
{
TableTitle.append(fname + " " + lname)`
etc finished by:

`do_table_refresh();
    }`

I'll post it all as a separate reply rather than a comment if you wish it to be clearer

Comment: Please go ahead and make an edit to the original post with this information. It will be easier to see. I'm still not able to really understand the problem though. What is `do_table_refresh()` doing? I'm not sure why you aren't just storing all the data in one array and appending new data to that array asynchronously.

Comment: I was waiting for you to respond all day already, thanks! I would store all the data in an array if I could. Problem is for swift to get stuff from JSON is tough and the examples I found have it done that way. Trust me, I've been coding PHP for 10 years now, but Xcode has a steep learning curve. I'll edit the original post in a minute to show you what I currently have

Comment: Okay. I'll be waiting.

Comment: OK Done. Please take a look. Note the comments in the prepareforsegue function in particular

Comment: After looking at your code, I still think that the example I've given still applies. You shouldn't be displaying different information in the tableview depending on if the searchResultsController is active or not. Just store your data, and always display the filtered data. You are going to have to add the new entries to your base data and, if it fits the filter, your filtered data, as it is loaded.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyM, I'm getting an error "Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> Bool)' when I try to implement your code

Comment: Sorry, `string` should be `string: String`. Editing now

Comment: That only changed the error to read: "Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((String) -> Bool)'"   !

Comment: Hey @AnthonyM , any suggestion? We took it this far, I'm sure we're almost done. If possible, maybe you can email me a working example ?

Comment: I just tossed it in a playground and got the same error as you. Turns out, you can't use `contains()` on a ` String`. Fixing it right now with an answer that actually compiles.

Comment: Thanks. I enlisted the help of a proffesional coder for a fee who took your code and built on it further. It now works as intended. I will post it all as an answer to my question in a day or two. Thanks for your help!